# Moving my bcd from HDD to SSD - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, bcd

I have windows 7 installed on my SSD, but the /boot/ and bootmgr are on my hard-drive. I want to move them to my SSD for faster booting times.

So i figured that I can fix the problem using the Windows startup repair tool.

I made a bootable windows 7 flash drive, and ran Windows startup repair. However, it exits with an error. I also can't see my OS in the list of installed OSs.

I then tried fixing via the command prompt with bootrec /fixmbr, bootrec /fixboot, bootrec /rebuildbcd.

Bootrec /rebuildbcd finds the OS, but gives me the error "The requested system device cannot be found" when i try fixing it.

Does anyone know why this is failing?  I read somewhere that the Windows Repair environment doesn't support a flash drive, which is why I'm getting that error. Is this true?

Unforunately my dvd drive is playing up so I can't use it to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind!

Managed to do it with EasyBCD -> BCD Backup/Repair -> Change boot drive.